# Cannot see the image that I uploaded in an answer

Tags: discussion

As a part of an answer, I uploaded an image. But I do not see that image in the answer at all.
The link to the question is as below. What am I doing wrong here?

[How can I stop wasting food?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/6676/how-can-i-stop-wasting-food/6699#6699)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see it.  Are you using Firefox?  You might have blocked images from imgur.com, or something like that.

Comment: I also can see one image (a meal planning worksheet).

Comment: I am using chrome with AdBlock + installed as an extension. maybe that is blocking the img? I'll check with firefox to verify. Nope still can't see the image. I guess maybe the company firewall is blocking it for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

We use imgur.com for image hosting

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/new-image-upload-support/

It sounds like your office is blocking that sevice.